# Table with several toggle triggers needing to be controlled by one piece of jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, html-table, toggle, show-hide

I have a table I am working on in ASP.NET that has 2 hidden rows for every main row, these rows are to add comments in a textbox or use the listbox in the 2nd hidden row to populate the textbox with pre-made comments. There will be an unknown amount of rows as it is based off data in our DB for each client. One the main row there is an image in the last column that is the click trigger to show the rows hidden behind it. The click evt I am using isn't working for some reason. Any help would be great.

Note: I am also using a for loop to count where my click event happens, when the table is finished the for loop will be ran off a counter from the code behind, so the "<= 7" is just for testing purposes.

HTML:

```
  <table id="mfCriteriaTable">
                <tr class="whiteBack mfTableBorder">
                    <td class="mfRightCol showCell" width="140px" align="left">Category</td>
                    <td class="colOne" width="600px" align="left">Criteria for achieving this element of service quality is listed here. Additional Detail click info</td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:RadioButton ID="mfScoreRad1" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:CheckBox ID="mfNA1" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:CheckBox ID="mfND1" runat="server" /></td> 
                    <td width="75px" align="center"><a href="#" id="mfComments1"><img src="Images/blue_info_tag.png" alt="" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="whiteBack" id="commentRow1" style="display:none;"><td colspan="6" id="tdComment1" height="30px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtComments1" CssClass="mfTextComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
                <tr class="whiteBack" id="slTableComments1" style="display:none;">
                     <td colspan="6" height="30px">
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lbComments1" runat="server" Height="20px" ToolTip="Please select a comment from this list or create your own in the text area above.">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 1">This is where comment number one will be, this is a longer comment just to see how it will all fit together.</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 2">This is a 2nd comment that is a bit shorter but shows usability. </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 3">And this is a 3rd comment so you are almost done.</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="whiteBack mfTableBorder">
                    <td class="mfRightCol showCell" width="140px" align="left">Category</td>
                    <td class="colOne" width="600px" align="left">Criteria for achieving this element of service quality is listed here. Additional Detail click info</td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:RadioButton ID="mfScoreRad2" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:CheckBox ID="mfNA2" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><asp:CheckBox ID="mfND2" runat="server" /></td> 
                    <td width="75px" align="center"><a href="#" id="mfComments2"><img src="Images/blue_info_tag.png" alt="" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="whiteBack" id="commentRow2" style="display:none;"><td colspan="6" id="tdComment2" height="30px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtComments2" CssClass="mfTextComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
                <tr class="whiteBack" id="slTableComments2" style="display:none;">
                     <td colspan="6" height="30px">
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lbComments2" runat="server" Height="20px" ToolTip="Please select a comment from this list or create your own in the text area above.">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 1">This is where comment number one will be, this is a longer comment just to see how it will all fit together.</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 2">This is a 2nd comment that is a bit shorter but shows usability. </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Comment 3">And this is a 3rd comment so you are almost done.</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Javascript:

```
     function assignClickHandlerFor(num) {

            window.console && console.log('#mfComments' + num);
            $('#mfComments' + num).click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();

                var $aBox = $(evt.currentTarget); 

                $aBox.find('tr#commentRow' + num).toggle;
                $aBox.find('tr#slTableComments' + num).toggle;
            });
    }

    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        assignClickHandlerFor(i);
    }
```

Comment: In the code you provided the function assignClickHandlerFor() is never called, hence the click event is never defined.

Comment: @Lokase The formatting was just messy and made it seem that way.  It is called in the loop.  I re-formatted it for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make selection easier, give all your clickable images `class="mfComments"`, then :

```
$(function() {
    $('.mfComments').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").next("tr").andSelf().toggle();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure about the loop counter business. I can't understand what it is supposed to achieve.

Comment: I don't think the `andSelf` should be there.  I don't see where he is toggling the main row.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, Maybe I misread the question .... I'll go aback and read it again ....

Comment: James is right, I don't need the first row toggled as it will always be visible.

Comment: I think it's OK. By the time the expression gets to the second `.next("tr")`, `andSelf()` merges it with the first `.next("tr")`. Thus the next two `<tr>' elements are selected. The first row is not in the selection and won't be toggled.

Comment: This is sort of working, it beings up my 2nd hidden row, but with that I should be able to get it working for both rows. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Oh you are correct Beet, at first I removed the andSelf, I just put it back and both rows are showing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot That's my mistake. I looked at it too quickly and thought the `andSelf` was referring to the `closest` not the first `next`.

Comment: `andSelf()` is a slightly misleading name for the method. It merges the current selection with one level down in jQuery's internal collection stack. It's easy to think that `andSelf` relates to the original collection at the left hand end of the method chain, which can be the case, but not when more than one change to the collection has been made in the chain.

Comment: Thanks for the info Beetroot, it is very useful to a JQ newb.

Comment: Bobby, get your mind round `andSelf()` and the rest is plain sailing :)

Answer (score 1):

`toggle` is a method and therefor needs `()` after it.  Also, `find` looks **within** an element.  You don't want to look within your `td`.

```
$('tr#commentRow' + num).toggle();
$('tr#slTableComments' + num).toggle();
```

You might also consider putting classes on these elements and then using things like `closest`, `prev`, `next`, etc. to located the appropriate elements rather than this method of incrementing `id`s.  It will require a bit of a re-write but will likely be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the typo catch, not exactly sure why i forgot the ()... as for closest and next they seem to not want to work when looking for 2 separate items but I will try to rework it.

Comment: @BobbyFarrow Beetroot's answer is roughly what I was reffering to.